# Reverse LinkedList - linked list implement

Tags: algorithm, linked-list, reverse

This is simple question from the LeetCode : Reverse LinkedList
I have two similar code and I can't figure it out what is difference between two but it outputs different result.

First while loop results correct answer but second one has wrong answer. 
Instead of `temp = current`. next, I just store current to temp
and at the last line of the while loop, I correctly switch current to temp.next.
I think they should result the same answer 
but when Input `{1,2,3,4,5}`  then second solution got wrong answer `{1}`.

```
ListNode reverse = null;
ListNode current = head;

while(current != null){
  ListNode temp = current.next;
  current.next = reverse;
  reverse = current;
  current = temp;
}
```

Here is the second while loop.

```
while(current != null){
  ListNode temp = current;
  current.next = reverse;
  reverse = current;
  current = temp.next;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the second snippet, it may seem that `current = temp.next` sets `current` to its `next`value from the top of the loop/the start or the current iteration - after all, nobody assigned something to `temp.next`.
But after `temp = current`, both are names for the same thing, and `current.next = reverse` overwrites something that will be needed and hasn't been saved.

Answer (score 1):

```
while(current != null){
    // This line temp is keeping the reference  of current variable
    ListNode temp = current;
    // now temp and current both pointing to same value

    // This line will make the next of current variable pointing to reverse reference
    // as current and temp were same so next of temp is also pointing to the reverse
    current.next = reverse;

    // now the reverse will be changed and point to the current reference
    reverse = current;
    // so up to here reverse, temp, current all pointing to the same location
    // as all are pointing same so temp.next,curr.next and reverse.next
    // will store the previous reference 

    // current will point back to the reverse value
    // no increment is done in the whole loop
    current = temp.next;
}
```